# Vuejs extending a parent component from child

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to put HTML from a child component in a parent component.

ChildComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <parent>
    <h3>test</h3>
  </parent>
</template>
```

Much like Laravel's `@yield` and `@section`

In my scenario, I have the menubars for my app in the parent `<template>` and want to fill the space beneath it via the child component.

Does anyone know whether and/or how it's possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue by putting `<router-view></router-view>` inside my parent component in the place where I want the child component.

And I put the child component in the `children` in the router.

```
{
  path: '/parent',
  name: 'Parent',
  component: Parent,
  children: [
    {
      path: '/parent/child',
      name: 'Child',
      component: Child
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to extend without the use of VueRouter, take a look at the slots docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Single-Slot